# Would it be a bad idea to use a For loop to create multiple JLabels that will be part of the implementation of an ActionListener later on?

Tags: java, for-loop, actionlistener, jlabel

I am trying to create multiple copies of the same JLabel. Something like,

```
    int totalLbls = 6;

        JLabel lbl[] = new JLabel[totalLbls];

        for (int i = 0; i <totalLbls;i++){

             lbl[i] = new JLabel("default");
             subPanel.add(lbl[i]);
                }
```

The labels I am creating will eventually be used to display data. When a JButton "Send" is clicked, these JLabels will display the relevant data which makes use of methods from an External JAR file.

Each JLabel has to display it's own unique data. So would I have to manually create 6 JLabels and manually "map" the data to each JLabel or can this be done with the for loop I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a very good idea ,arrays make it much easier to handle a reasonably large set of identical data, the hugest benefit being you don't have to name individual objects.But if you want each of them to have a certain size based on the data being displayed you are going to have to manipulate them outside of a loop anyway but still..... No names to worry about.